# WINCE Installation prerequisites

Tags: visual-studio-2005, windows-ce

I am working on wince for a device having Standard Development Kit.
Now my aim is to develop applications for that.So please give me the prerequisites for installation and details about that.
Please help me i am sticking in installation for more than two months.

Thanks,
Pooja.

Comment: Your question is unclear.  "installation" of what?  Tools to develop?  Applications on the device?

Comment: I am attempting to install WINCE on a WINDOWS-XP based system.I came to know that its prerequisites are Visual studio 2005 and its patches,WINCE 6.0 and its patches.Since i am working on a device based on WINCE i am asking about configuration of WINCE for that device.

Comment: Actually I did all installation steps but when i am attempting to run sample application i am getting the following error Compiling... stdafx.cpp C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\VC\ce\atlmfc\include\afx.h(53) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'new.h': No such file or directory

Answer (score 2):

First, Windows CE is an operating system.  It's not something you really "install" and based on your comments I believe you actually are talking about "Platform Builder", which is the development tool for creating Windows CE OS images.

That said, if all you want to do is create an *application* then you don't need or want to install Platform Builder.  You simply install Visual Studio. I'd recommend Visual Studio 2008 (Pro or better for device development), but you can also use Visual Studio 2005 (Standard or better for device development).

If you have Studio installed and selected "Smart Device Programmability" in the setup, you will have Smart Device Application as one of the project types offered when you create a new project.  Select that and walk through the Wizard.

If you are using C/C++, then you also need to install an SDK.  It's very unusual to use the old "Standard SDK" as it didn't actually meet any real devices, which is why Microsoft also dropped support for it.  Typically the device OEM will provide an SDK for the OS image that was actually built.  Install the SDK and when you walk through the "new smart device project" wizard, you will see it as an available target platform.

Comment: Thanks alot @ctacke for your clear explanation.Now i am clear to some extent and i will move forward to develop applications by discussing with my team members.Actually i am new to windows ,till now i worked on Linux.

Comment: If application is supposed to be working on various Windows CE devices then "Standard SDK" is the only option. Actually I didnot know Microsoft dropped support for it, I work on application that is using Standard SDK and it is shipped with hundrets of Windows CE devices.

Comment: I've seen a CE device shipped that someone actually used the Standard SDK for, and I ran the SW team for an OEM for years. I've also been doing CE app dev since CE 1.0. Standard SDK caused nothing but confusion when it was released. As a concept, it may have had some merit, but the way they implemented it was problematic. They've still not solved the problem as of WEC 2013, IMO